# python-docx trailing trilling whitepsaces not showing correctly

Tags: python, python-docx

**Goal**

I am trying to add a text to a table cell where the text is a combination of 2 strings and the space between the strings of variable size so that the final text has the same length and it appears as if the second string is right aligned.

I can either use format or ljust to combine the strings in python.

```py
period = "from Monday to Friday"
item_text = "Some txt"
item_text2 = "Some other txt"

t1 = "t1: {:<30}{:0}".format(item_text,period)
t2 = "t2: {:<30}{:0}".format(item_text2,period)

t3 = f"t3: {item_text.ljust(30)}{period}"
t4 = f"t4: {item_text2.ljust(30)}{period}"

from pprint import pprint
pprint(t1)
pprint(t2)
pprint(t3)
pprint(t4)
```

**Text in python with variable space length between strings**

[image]

However, if I add this text to a docx table, the space between the strings changes.

```py
from docx import Document

doc = Document()

# Creating a table object
table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=2, style="Table Grid")

table.rows[0].cells[0].text = f"{item_text.ljust(30)}{period}"
table.rows[1].cells[0].text = f"{item_text2.ljust(30)}{period}"


def set_col_widths(table):
    widths = tuple( Cm(val) for val in [15,8])
    for row in table.rows:
        for idx, width in enumerate(widths):
            row.cells[idx].width = width

set_col_widths(table)


doc.save("test_whitespace.docx")
```

**Text in word. Space between strings changed.**

[image]

Note
I am aware that I could add a table to the table cell and left adjust the left and right adjust the right but that seems like way more code to write.

**Question**
Why is the spacing changing in the word document and how can I create the text differently to get the desired goal?

Comment: My intermediate solution is to use a if condition and as many tabs as needed  if var = "Some txt " then;  cell ==  f"\t" else cell ==  f"\t\t"  but I would love a more flexible solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a monospace font?

[This was my result when I changed it to Courier New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRAXQ.png)